# Drupal adding system actions

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I want to create an action which sends an email, but it is different from Drupal's built-in email-action.  My question is that how should I write one extra action (which is advanced based on Drupal's definition) and add them to this list?

Should I write a module?

Or should I edit the existing files? (which oh! weird)

Or there is already a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples module has a good explanation of creating a custom action which can be found [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/action_example%21action_example.module/7)

Otherwise you could have a look at using [Rules module][2]

[2]: https://www.drupal.org/project/rules to create your functunality.